# string to numerical, withouth spaces

Tags: string, matlab, double, string-parsing

In MATLAB if I have a string like:

```
 a='0.424870551E+03-0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03';
```

If I use

```
 b=str2num(a);
```

I get

```
 b =324.7575  470.2208;
```

That is, MATLAB performed the operation for the first two numbers rather than give a 3 column vector.

Is there a possibility to convert a into a 3 column vector without using `textscan`?

This might seem as a pretty easy thing; I didn't found no further information in the `str2num` documentation, so that's the reason why I'm asking,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the format correctly and it will be interpreted right even without the space:

```
>> sscanf(a,'%E')
ans =
  424.8706
 -100.1130
  470.2208
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce a blank space before each minus sign, except if the minus sign is in an exponent (thanks to Rafael Monteiro for noting this). That way Matlab knows they are different numbers:

```
a = '0.424870551E+03-0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03';
ind = a=='-'; %// detect positions of "-" ...
ind2 = [0 a(1:end-1)=='E'];
ind = ind & ~ind2; %// ... but not in exponents. Thanks to Rafael Monteiro
asep = repmat(' ',1,numel(a)+nnz(ind)); %// initiallize with spaces
asep((1:numel(a))+cumsum(ind)) = a; %// fill in a. Leave a blank before each "-"
b = str2num(asep);
```

This gives:

```
a =
0.424870551E+03-0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03

asep =
0.424870551E+03 -0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03

b =
  424.8706 -100.1130  470.2208
```

Comment: You could use `asep = strrep(a, '-', ' -')` as well. :)

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Hey, what's waaaay easier! Add that to your answer, it's your idea :-)

Comment: Therefore, he could just change his code to `b=str2num(strrep(a, '-', ' -'));`

Comment: I only have one concern: is that possible there are values like this: `0.424870551E-03`? (with the minus on the end)

Comment: Hmm... Well thought. Perhaps it would be better to use `regexprep` then

Comment: Perhaps. But as his example contained a negative number, that probably wouldn't happen.

Comment: I have corrected the issue with the netagive the exponent. Thanks for your suggestion, @RafaelMonteiro

Comment: What if i have multiple rows

Comment: @user2751649 That can probably be solved. But it wasn't in the original question. Anyway... how do you have those rows? A cell array? It would be best to post a different question

Comment: yes it might be possible to have E-01 what about that?

Comment: @user2751649 That's already solved in my question. See above comments

Comment: Is it good if i edit my question?, for multiple string rows?, or is it neccesary to create a new question?

Comment: @user2751649 Generally, if the question is fundamentally altered I suggest creating a new question. Not sure in this case. It depends on how you have those multiple rows defined. For example, if it's a cell array of strings, it can be solved easily

Comment: In that case I don't see a better way than using a `for` loop over each string. Something like: `for a = cellArrayOfStrings` and then the above code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50832/discussion-between-user2751649-and-luis-mendo)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there no space between the first and second numbers. Then, the function thinks you want to subtract them.

There are four ways you can do that.

For the first three, that's what you get:

```
str2num('0.424870551E+03-0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03')
str2num('0.424870551E+03 - 0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03')
str2num('0.424870551E+03- 0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03')
```

ans =

324.7575  470.2208

But doing like this, it will get that you want the three numbers separately:

```
str2num('0.424870551E+03 -0.100113019E+03 0.470220758E+03')
```

ans =

424.8706 -100.1130  470.2208

Comment: I know that if i add a space i would get the 3 column vector. The problem is that i'm getting the data from an external file...containing a lot of mixed data

Comment: Do you always have 3 values on each line?